# Login failed while connecting to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I have created WPF application which has MDF file. When I added MDF file to my solutions folder It automatically created a connection string for me

```
     <add name="Connection"
    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=C:\Users\Public\Desktop\MyDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I **Deployed** my application using SQL Server Compact ([as described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa983340%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)). But When I run my Application I am getting exception

> Cannot open database "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\MyDatabase.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed.
>
> Login failed for user 'MY-PC\NAME'.

I am using Windows Authentication for my SQL Server

Comment: try change the parameter "Integrated Security=True;"  to "Integrated Security=False;" in the connection string.

Comment: When false, User ID and Password are specified in the connection. When true, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.
Recognized values are true, false, yes, no, and sspi (strongly recommended), which is equivalent to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your connection string as follows:

```
<add name="Connection"
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=C:\Users\Public\Desktop\MyDatabase.mdf;persist security info=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;"providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Is it really possible to connect directely to a MDF file ?

Comment: Yes its possible through localDb connection